# SINCH SDK Bandwidth

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, sinch, android-sinch-api

I am using Sinch SDK for voice/video calls in my app and I was wondering if there are any way to check the current internet bandwidth of the call similar to [Twilio's Bandwidth Profile API.](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/using-bandwidth-profile-api) . I scoured the documentation and haven't found anything or perhaps I am looking for something different entirely. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no API available for checking the current bandwidth available from Sinch for the Voice / Video calls.